# Value Relation Widget not working in QField; QFIeld not displaying values

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud, valuerelation

I am setting up many Value Relations Widgets in QGIS to have drop-down selections that can be used in QField for data collection. The Widget works perfectly in QGIS, but when synced to QFeildCloud and opened in QField, the Value Realtion Widgets don't display any values at all when I click on the drop-down arrow, not even "blank" values.

I've tried to use loaded data from layer in a Value Map Widget as an alternative, and that displays the values, but it puts them out of order in the drop-down list, and I'd like to keep the order the same as they are entered in their respective layers.

Is there a remedy to this issue or a better way to do this?

I've included a screen shot of the Widget settings in the Layer Properties Attribute Form.

[image]

Comment: It seems a few people have been having this issue with QFieldCloud and non-geometry layers, does https://github.com/opengisch/qfieldcloud/issues/874#issuecomment-1928083350 this solution help?

Comment: yes that made the Value Relation Widgets display properly.

But now Add New Feature Button (+) on my Relations Editor Widgets doesn't work in QField.
Do I need to reconfigure those relations before re-uploading the project as well?

Comment: Possibly. But looking at more recent comments to that link, the amazing QField devs have patched the fix. Maybe if you update your QFieldSync plugin and try again?